# Use “at least” in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Which of these sentences is correct?

1. I will not attend the next 3 lectures **at least**.
2. I will not attend **at least** the next 3 lectures.

What I am trying to say is that the minimum number of lectures I will be absent from is 3.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, the scope of an adverbial element (such as ***at least*** here) is often ambiguous. See [Does changing the position of an adverb change the meaning of these sentences?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3741/does-changing-the-position-of-an-adverb-change-the-meaning-of-these-sentences) - which focuses specifically on ***only***, but the general principle<sup>1</sup> applies more more widely.

In example #1 as cited, ***at least*** could specifically modify ***the next 3 lectures***. Speaker commits to not attending ("boycotting"<sup>2</sup>) a minimum of 3 lectures, but leaves it open as to whether he will in fact boycott ***more than 3 lectures***.

BUT - #1 could be a "whole sentence adverb", whereby speaker commits to boycotting a few lectures as his minimum response to some situation, but leaves it open as to whether he might take some *further* action (such as writing to his university's chancellor to demand that the relevant lecture-giving professor be removed from his post, who knows?).

---

TL;DR:  Example #1 is ambiguous, but example #2 can *only* have the first meaning above.

---

<sup>1</sup> The "general principle" being that *by default* we assume an adverbial / adjectival element references / modifies ***the nearest credible candidate verb / noun phrase*** (the nearest *preceding* element if there's also an "equidistant" *following* element). But we take *pragmatics* into account when identifying ***credible*** referents (we choose the interpretation that makes most sense).

<sup>2</sup> Perhaps speaker's impending lecture non-attendance is due to illness or holiday plans, rather than some kind of protest / boycott. But that's *semantics*, which doesn't affect the *syntax* under discussion.